# Assembly - Stack , Procedures, ESP, EBP, SS - Help me understand

Tags: assembly, stack, cpu-registers, masm32

I'm having difficulty understanding what's going on here, as far as what is on the stack, and where registers ESP, EBP, and SS are pointing to at the point in the code that says HERE.
Here's my code

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.data?
    value DWORD ?
.code
start:
    push 42
    push 5
    call xyz
    mov value, EAX
    print str$(value)
    exit
xyz:
    enter 4, 0
    ; HERE
    leave
    ret 8
end start
```

So I need to see what's on the stack.

Here's my best guess as to where everything is (below is a text stack)

[image: My Attempt 2.0]

Comment: You need to read the manual about what the `enter` does. Hint: it does not push the two operands onto the stack. Also, `ESP` will always point to what is known as the _top of stack_, which in your drawing is actually at the bottom.

Comment: @Jester I should have said that in this stack, it grows from the bottom up, so first in last out. I read enter creates a stack frame, and leave destroys that stack frame. I'm just not quite understanding it. Any more help would be great. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If your stack grows from bottom up, then it's even worse of course. The first thing put on the stack is 42, so by that logic that should be at the bottom. PS: you can single step the code in a debugger and see what happens at each instruction ;)

Comment: @Jester Since the first thing put onto the stack is 42, shouldn't that be on TOP? I uploaded a better diagram, to show my understanding (or lack thereof). I will try to use my Visual studio debugger, thanks for the tip. I believe that enter 4, 0 allocates 4 segments of the stack for the procedure?

Comment: It was you who claimed that in your diagram it grows from bottom up! Clearly, if you put 5 in after 42, then 5 must be above 42 since it grows up.  First 42, then the 5 makes it grow ... up. Of course in memory x86 stack grows down and your diagram actually works for that case except you put the ESP and EBP in the wrong place.

Comment: I'm sorry - I guess I'm just not understanding it. In my head, 42 goes in. 5 goes under that. therefore 42 is above 5. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Yes that's how it works. But that actually means it grows down :) The growing happened under the item already in there, like the root of a plant.

Comment: I would love to hear what you think the stack looks like @Jester. That way I can compare my revised attempts.

Comment: up/down.. doesn't matter much, it's just mental image. [`push dword 5`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_269.html) will do: `sub esp,4` (if `esp` was 0x1000, then it will become `0x0FFC`, and `mov [esp],dword 5`. So after that push at address `0x0FFC` there will be four bytes `05 00 00 00`, and `esp` will point to the first one with `5`.  About [`enter`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_78.html) read the description + "operation" here.

Comment: I also did add [Z80 stack](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/assembly/4957/the-stack/17507/zilog-z80-stack#t=201612090046265334076) article in assembly docs... but the subtle differences in Z80 vs x86 asm may make this one confusing for you? It's very similar how x86 works, just everything is 8/16bit, and there were no `enter/leave` instructions, `ex` is `xchg`, etc... Principle is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack will look like:

```
42
5
return address
previous ebp pushed by "enter"; new ebp points here
4 uninitialized bytes due to "enter"; esp points here
```

You can of course see this in a debugger:

```
6       push 42
(gdb) s
start () at test.s:7
7       push 5
(gdb) 
start () at test.s:8
8       call xyz
(gdb) p/x $eip+5
$5 = 0x80483e5         # This is the return address (call is 5 bytes)
(gdb) p/x $ebp
$6 = 0xffffda78        # This is the ebp in the caller
(gdb) s
xyz () at test.s:11
11      enter 4, 0
(gdb) 
12      leave
(gdb) p/x $ebp
$7 = 0xffffd9ec        # This is the current ebp
(gdb) p/x $esp
$8 = 0xffffd9e8        # This is esp
(gdb) x/x $esp
0xffffd9e8: 0x0804841b # Top of stack, 4 garbage bytes, esp points here
(gdb) x
0xffffd9ec: 0xffffda78 # Saved ebp, current ebp points here
(gdb) x
0xffffd9f0: 0x080483e5 # Return address
(gdb) x
0xffffd9f4: 0x00000005 # argument "5"
(gdb) x
0xffffd9f8: 0x0000002a # argument "42"
```

`SS` is the stack segment, it is preset by the OS, it doesn't point anywhere but has base address 0 and is not changed.

Note that `enter x, 0` is equivalent to:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, x
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @jester. This really helps.